# Producing uppercase letters without pointers

Tags: c, string, character

I am trying to write a function, uppercase, that converts all lowercase characters in a string into their uppercase equivalents.

However, I am getting a Bus 10 error in my code. I know that string literals cannot be modified in C; so, I am not sure if this is the right approach.

My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int uppercase(char source[])
{
 int i;

 for(i=0; i<=strlen(source); ++i)
    if (source[i]>= 'a' && source[i]<= 'z')
        source[i]= source[i]-'a' +'A';
    else 
        source[i]=source[i];
}

int main(){
    uppercase("cold");

    return 0;
}
```

Ideally this function should return COLD.I suppose the error lies in my whole if statement.

Comment: `char s[] = "cold"; uppercase(s);`

Comment: You've answered your own question. And what do you mean by "return"?

Comment: And what on earth is the point of `source[i] = source[i]`??

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been clearer. I do not know how to fix the error in this case. The point of that is to make no change. I guess it is redundant?

Comment: I guess you should also include the uppercase() function/method.

Comment: Thank you, chux. But can you provide an explanation?

Comment: @XiJiaopin Others have well provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you get a crash is that your code modifies a string literal. Characters inside string literals are placed in protected memory area, and therefore may not be changed: it us undefined behavior.

Replace this

```
uppercase("cold");
```

with this:

```
char cold[] = "cold";
uppercase(cold);
```

Now the characters of the string are placed in a modifiable area of memory, allowing you to make changes as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your absolutly working with pointers without even to know it.

In  your function definition

```
int uppercase(char source[])
```

`char source[]` is considered by the compiler as a pointer to char (`char *source`)

So when passing a string literal to `uppercase()` your just passing it's adress. Then in your function your trying to modify it which leads to undefined behaviour.

Also you can't return a whole array so you just return a pointer to it.

```
char *uppercase(char source[])
{
     int i;
     size_t len = strlen(source);
     char *tmp;
     tmp = malloc(len+1);
     if (tmp!=NULL){
         memcpy(tmp, source, len+1);
         for(i=0; i<len; ++i){
            if (tmp[i]>= 'a' && tmp[i]<= 'z'){
                tmp[i]= tmp[i]-'a' +'A';
            }
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Then:

```
int main(){
    char *str = uppercase("cold");
    printf("%s", str);
    free(str);

    return 0;
}
```

You complete code: http://ideone.com/BJHDIF

Comment: You need to allocate space for the null terminator and should really add a `free(tmp);` in `main`

Comment: Doesn't the strlen includes the null terminator? why to free tmp, this will leads to losing it because the function is returning it.

Comment: No, `strlen` does not include the terminator.  You can't call `free` on a dynamically allocated return from `uppercase` until you're finished with it but you should free it at some point.  Your suggestion leaks this memory; not a big deal in this tiny program but very bad advice for programming in general.

Comment: You forgot the null terminator :)

Comment: I don't think so - `malloc(len+1)` allocates space for it and `strcpy` copies it.  I had missed that the loop finished one character early though - that's now corrected.

Comment: Since you already have length using `strcpy` is an overkill: use `memcpy(tmp, source, len + 1)` (I would have copied string in the cycle though instead). Return type of `strlen()` is `size_t`, not `int`, same for argument type of `malloc`. You also do `len = strlen(tmp);` while you meant `source` here and not `tmp`. And you really should check whether `malloc` returned `NULL`.

Comment: @ZyX how to check if malloc has returned NULL and why is memcpy better than strcpy

Comment: @rullof 1. ?! How to check whether pointer is NULL? Use `if (tmp == NULL)`. 2. `strcpy` operates on strings with unknown length. I.e. it has to operate on strings in a fashion that it will not access memory after NUL byte. `memcpy` copies a continuous memory chunk with given start position and length. It does not need to check whether given chunk contains some specific byte, neither it needs to process memory from specific position (i.e. start of the chunk) and in given direction (i.e. from start to end) meaning that more optimizations are possible in `memcpy` implementation.

Comment: Note about malloc: it returns NULL if there is no memory. In this case your app may be expected to try freeing some memory, but most likely just crash complaining about absence of memory (if you do not add this check it will crash without easy to understand message because you try to write to address 0x0 (NULL)).

Comment: `!==`? It is not JavaScript. You can also drop `else` branch: if `tmp == NULL` there is exactly no difference between `return NULL` and `return tmp`. And `main()` does not care about the case when `uppercase()` function returned `NULL`.

Comment: Uggg missed again. I should go suiside

Comment: The main thing I do not like in C is that sometimes more then half of the code is doing error handling. More then half of the error handling is passing errors from the callee to the caller.